# MongodDB $pull only one element from array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, database, nosql

I have a document with an array inside, like this:

```
"userTags" : [
        "foo",
        "foo",
        "foo",
        "foo",
        "moo",
        "bar"
    ]
```

If I perform `db.products.update({criteriaToGetDocument}, {$push: {userTags: "foo"}}}` I can correctly insert another instance of `foo` into the array.

However, if I do `db.products.update({criteriaToGetDocument}, {$pull: {userTags: "foo"}}}` then it removes *all* instances of `foo` from the array, leaving me with:

```
"userTags" : [
        "moo",
        "bar"
    ]
```

This won't do at all, I only want to pull one item from the array rather than all of them. How can I alter the command so that only one `foo` is removed? Is there some sort of `$pullOnce` method that can work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is nothing like this at the moment. A lot of people already requested the feature and you can track it in [mongodb Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1014). As far as you can see it is not resolved and also not scheduled (which means you have no luck in the near future).

The only option is to use application logic to achieve this would be:

1. find element that you want and that has userTags as foo
2. iterate through userTags and remove one foo from it
3. update that element with a new userTags

Keep in mind that this operation breaks atomicity, but because Mongo has not provided a native method to do so, you will break atomicity in any way.

I moved one alternative solution to the new answer, because it does not answer this question, but represents one of the approaches to refactor existing schema. It also became so big, that started to be much bigger then the original answer.

Comment: This is...very annoying. I suppose another way would be to change my data design so that `userTags` is an object with `{tag: (numberofinstances)` and just increase/decrease this number whenever necessary, but I'd really rather not do that as it messes with the whoooole lot of other stuff!

Comment: I agree with you. It looks like this feature is really useful and without reading documentation one can misinterpret the idea of $pull. But people in mongo are doing a good job increasing the features of mongo during every release. So I do believe that one day you will see this out of the box. P.S. - vote for feature in the JIRA.

Comment: Nice edit. Can you suggest any commands that would check the tag existing then check if it's greater than one? Or would I have to find whether the `tag: {$exists: true}` in one lookup then do an update with the new tag number?

Comment: @Jascination the answer is in another answer. I put it there because it started to be bigger then original answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use this feature, you have to consider modifying your schema. One way to go is to do something like this:

```
"userTags" : {
   "foo" : 4,
   "moo": 1,
   "bar": 1
}
```

Where the number is the quantity of tags. This way you can use atomic $inc to add or remove the tag. While adding the new tag can be appropriate, while deleting the tags you have to be careful. You have to check that the tag exist and that it is >= then 1.

Here is how you can do it:

```
db.a.insert({
  _id : 1,
  "userTags" : {
     "foo" : 4,
     "moo": 1,
     "bar": 1
  }
})
```

To add one Tag you need to do just this:

```
db.a.update({_id : 1}, {$inc : {'userTags.zoo' : 1}})
```

If the tag did not existed before it will create it

To remove the Tag, you need to do a little bit more:

```
db.a.update({
  _id : 1,
  'userTags.moo' : {$gte : 1 }
}, {
   $inc : {'userTags.moo' : -1}
})
```

Here you are checking that the element exist and is bigger then 1 (no need to check for existence because $gte is doing this as well).

Keep in mind that this approach has one drawback. You can have some tags that are listed as fields, but are not real tags (they have a value of 0). So if you want to find all elements with tag foo you have to remember this and do something like this:

```
db.a.find({'userTags.zoo' : { $gte : 1}})
```

Also when you output all tags for an element, you might have the same problem. So you need to sanitize the output on application layer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a workaround and not a real solution but, as I ran into this same issue, I found that in PHP at least, you can do something like this:

```
// Remove up to two elements "bar" from an array called "foo" 
// in a document that matches the query {foo:"bar"}

$un_bar_qty = 2;
$un_bar_me  = $db->foo->findOne(array("foo"=>"bar"));
foreach($un_bar_me['bar'] as $foo => $bar) {
    if($bar == 'bar') {
        unset($un_bar_me['bar'][$foo]); 
        $un_bar_qty--;
    }
    if(!$un_bar_qty) break;
}
$db->foo->update(array('_id'=>$un_bar_me['_id']),$bar);
```

Document before:

```
{ 
    { foo: "bar" },
    { bar: [ "bar" , "bar" , "foo", "bar" ] }
}
```

Document after:

```
{ 
    { foo: "bar" },
    { baz: [ "foo", "bar" ] }
}
```

Not too bad of a way to do it. Certainly seemed less of a hassle to me than messing around with tags and increments, YMMV.