# What is a way to remove one item from an array of mostly identical items in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pull

Say I have this document in a MongoDB collection.

> {     stuff: [ a, a, b, a, b, a, a] }

I want to remove a single "b" from stuff.

If I do `$pull:{stuff:"b"}` then it removes both of the b's. I can't use $pop because the b's aren't on the end.

Just curious if there is a way that I'm missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongodDB $pull only one element from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463057/mongoddb-pull-only-one-element-from-array)

Comment: You're right, it is.